# Booting my desktop machine from SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I'm trying to figure out how to boot from my SSD.

I installed a new SSD and cloned my hard drive to it. The SSD is showing up in my drives list.

In the boot menu I have the 5 options:

P0 : dvdram
IBA get slot
P4: WDC WD10
P5: Samsung SSD
UEFI: WDC WD10

Of these only the last works. Even the P4 option doesn't work. As a result I am not able to boot from my SSD. I think I need to have my SSD with UEFI before it can boot, but am just not able to get that.

Answer (score 0):

The way win 10 boot prevents that.
The best way is to create a USB win 10 recovery media.

Boot from the recovery media and choose to repair your os installation in SSD.
You might disconnect the HDD from your system before doing that.

However, it is not advisable to run a cloned OS from HDD in your SSD. 
Windows 10 prepares many different setting according to your drive types. 
HDD or SSD.

SSD is more prone to write operation and excel in read.

I hopes that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I searched here and one of the options that I read about and hadn't tried was this:

1. Clone HDD to SSD
2. Turn off desktop
3. Open desktop box, take out SATA data cable from HDD and connect that to SSD
4. Restart computer
5. Connect HDD to computer with another SATA cable
6. Enjoy higher speeds